# Web application could not be started with Ubuntu 14.04, rbenv ruby 2.2.3p

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, rbenv

**My vps:**

- Ubuntu 14.04
- rbenv ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-linux]
- Rails 4.2.4
- Passenger + Apache

**When I deploy a ruby app:**

Web application could not be started.

```
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:430:in `activate_gem'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:297:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:435:in `running_bundler'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:296:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

Error ID
d999dc5f

Comment: do `gem install bundler`

Comment: Could you paste `ruby -v`?

Comment: Ruby -v: ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-linux]
I haved used gem install bundler and bundle install